# java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed

Tags: java, token, pkcs#11, sunpkcs11

I am writing a java program that needs to read a USB Token Flash Private Key to do something, but I got stuck in the first phase of this program and it throws Error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:377)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:108)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_TOKEN_NOT_PRESENT
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_GetTokenInfo(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.Token.<init>(Token.java:135)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.initToken(SunPKCS11.java:969)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:368)
    ... 2 more
```

Here's the peice of code that represents the error above:

```java
    String pkcs11Config = "name=eToken\nlibrary=C:\\Windows\\System32\\ShuttleCsp11_3003.dll";
    System.out.println("step 1");
    java.io.ByteArrayInputStream pkcs11ConfigStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
    Provider providerPKCS11 = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(pkcs11ConfigStream);
    java.security.Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);
    System.out.println("step 2");
```

I tried to reinstall the program which is inside this USB flash and I could successfully login and export public key and certificate.
I even restarted the pc, but none of them worked and I still got those errors.
Do you think my USB Token is corrupted or damaged? Cause if it is damaged it shouldn't login successfully...

I expect to pass this line of code:

```java
Provider providerPKCS11 = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(pkcs11ConfigStream);
```

Can someone please help me with this code?

Comment: Are you sure your token was designed to be used in this way?  Not all tokens are created equal.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hello, Yes I'm sure. Actually I searched for tokens like the one mentioned and found out I should use a library (in my case DLL) to communicate with them and this .dll library can retrieve private key when it's used along with custom packages and libraries form other programming languages (like java) but, it still doesn't let user to see what the private key is. I recently found out that when I install .exe program inside this USB Flash Token, it copies 2 .dll files and 1 .sig file in "C:\Windows\System32" folder and that's as far as I went.